# How can I fix that my web pages are not opening until I turn on VS Code live server?

Tags: html, web-services, visual-studio-code

I really want someone to help me. I have a serious issue with VS Code live server. Everything is perfectly working, but once I completed my project, I can't open my web pages without turning the live server on. Whenever I want to check my web pages, I have to open it in the VS Code, then turn on the live server. Is there a way I can fix it? I want to open web page directly rather than first open it in VS Code, then turn on the live server.

What is the solution? How can server run forever?

Answer (score 0):

You could open your HTML file directly to any web browser. You don't have to run “Live Server” to run your HTML File.